# How do I center text vertically and horizontally in Flutter?

Tags: user-interface, text, widget, alignment, flutter

I'd like to know how to center the contents of a Text widget vertically and horizontally in Flutter.
I only know how to center the widget itself using `Center(child: Text("test"))` but not the content itself. By default, it's aligned to the left. In Android, I believe the property of a TextView that achieves this is called `gravity`.

Example of what I want:

[image: centered text example]

Answer (score 546, accepted):

Text alignment center property setting only horizontal alignment.

[image]

I used below code to set text vertically and horizontally center.

[image]

Code:

```
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          "Hello World",
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: @Shelly  In some cases it won't work you need to add heightFactor:  property  also e.g :
Center(
                                  heightFactor: 2.3,
                                  child: Text('SELFIE',textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.black,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      )
                                  ),
                                ),

Comment: I took a look and agree. Changed this to be the correct answer since it centers horizontally and vertically.

Comment: If you find that the text is still not vertically centred, and you have set the height in TextStyle, remember to set leadingDistribution: TextLeadingDistribution.even as well in TextStyle.

Answer (score 115):

You can use `TextAlign` property of `Text` constructor.

```
Text("text", textAlign: TextAlign.center,)
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this was marked as the answer, as this only centers text horizontally, but the question asks for horizontally **and** vertically.

Comment: Yes this should be removed, it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 95):

I think a more flexible option would be to wrap the `Text()` with `Align()` like so:

```
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.center, // Align however you like (i.e .centerRight, centerLeft)
  child: Text("My Text"),
),
```

Using `Center()` seems to ignore `TextAlign` entirely on the Text widget. It will not align `TextAlign.left` or `TextAlign.right` if you try, it will remain in the center.

Comment: Much better answer is this one.

Comment: this should be the marked answer cause the question is about how to center a text in horizontal and vertical. Thank you!

Comment: This is the answer guys, just wondering why my text was not aligning with a bigger font size, Turns out that center it's weird with text and there is a breakpoint in wich will ignore the text size. Align seems not to have this issue... love u <3

Comment: You may need to set `TextStyle( leadingDistribution: TextLeadingDistribution.even)` too for large fonts to get them centered properly vertically.

Answer (score 19):

Wrap your text widget with `Align` and set `alignment` to `Alignment.center`.

```
                       child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: Text(
                            'Text here',
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,                          
                          ),
                        ),
```

This produced the best result for me.

Answer (score 12):

**The text title must be always on top.**

wrong way:

```
  child: Center(
    child: Text(
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      "Hello World",
    ),
  ),
```

right way:

```
  child: Center(
    child: Text(
      "Hello World",
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: Though you're technically correct, it is a syntax error to do it in the first way you described, so yes, but I think it's clear that that's not the way to do it since it won't even let you compile :p

Answer (score 11):

You  need to use `textAlign` property on the Text widget. It produced the best results for me

```
Text(
  'Hi there',
   textAlign: TextAlign.center,                          
 )
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are a intellij IDE user, you can use shortcut key `Alt+Enter` and then choose `Wrap with Center` and then add `textAlign: TextAlign.center`

Answer (score 6):

Put the Text in a Center:

```
Container(
      height: 45,
      color: Colors.black,
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
            'test',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 4):

Text element inside Center of SizedBox work much better way, below Sample code

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RawMaterialButton(
      fillColor: Colors.green,
      splashColor: Colors.greenAccent,
      shape: new CircleBorder(),
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              width: 100.0,
              height: 100.0,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                widget.buttonText,
                maxLines: 1,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)
              ),
              )
          )]
        ),
    ),
  onPressed: widget.onPressed
);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Overview: I used the Flex widget to center text on my page using the MainAxisAlignment.center along the horizontal axis.  I use the container padding to create a margin space around my text.

```
  Flex(
            direction: Axis.horizontal,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
                Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    child:
                        Text("No Records found", style: NoRecordFoundStyle))
  ])
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to set your Text widget property to set textAlign.center.

```
center(
   child : Text(
  'Hello',
   textAlign: TextAlign.center))
```

Comment: Center(
    child : Text(   "Text",
    textAlign: TextAlign.center))

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your Text widget inside the Align widget and add Alignment.center.

```
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  child: Text(
    'Some Text',
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score -2):

maybe u want to provide the same width and height for 2 container

```
Container(
            width: size.width * 0.30, height: size.height * 0.4,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6)
            ),
            child: Center(
              child: Text(categoryName, textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 17,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),),
            ),
```