# Can't align a text vertically in a container in flutter

Tags: user-interface, flutter, text, widget, alignment

I have tried the solutions posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50554110/how-do-i-center-text-vertically-and-horizontally-in-flutter) but none of them seemed to work.

```
        Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
            "Financial Formulas\n",
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
            ),
          ),
          color: Colors.blue,
          width: 150,
          height: 35,
        ),
```

Comment: Use `Financial\nFormulas`

Comment: Remove height and "\n" both

Answer (score 2):

When you add a `\n` to your text, it takes an extra line. Remove it and your text will be in the middle:

[image: Formulas]

Answer (score 0):

To break your text into new lines, use the `/n`.

In your case change your code to the one below:

```
   Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
            // Financial will be on a line and Formulas on another line
            "Financial\nFormulas",
            // the text align property tells you how to arrange the texts
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
            ),
          ),
          color: Colors.blue,
          width: 150,
          height: 35,
        ),
```